# Restrict service account in organization level from specific projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I created a ServiceAccount in a specific GCP project with a "Storage Viewer" permissions. Then, I added that SA in the organization level, so it will be allowed to view the storage buckets of all the projects inside the organization.
However, I want to restrict that SA for viewing the GCS for some projects under the organization. Is it possible? Can I restrict SA in organization level performing its authorized actions in specific projects?

I followed this guide: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts, but haven't found something useful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict an org level permission downwards. Org Level Permissions are inherited at all folders/projects under that org. The only way i can think of you can solve this problem is to grant the permissions at the folder level. And group the projects where you don't want these permissions to exist under a specific folder where you don't assign that role

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with restricting the access through policies at the folder level, but currently we have lots of projects with various IAM management that couldn't be gathered into folders.

Comment: I found a way to restrict the access to specific projects without using folders - it is possible to create a tag in the organization level, attach that tag to the relevant projects that need to be accessed by the SA, and add a condition using that tag inside the SA's permission (org level). That solved the issue.

Comment: Good you used IAM conditions than. Can you add that as an answer and i will upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a tag in the organization level, attach that tag to the relevant projects that need to be accessed by the SA, and add a condition using that tag inside the SA's permission (org level).

**In order to make that work, please follow the next steps:**

1. A tag in the organization level should to be created: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing#creating_tag
2. The tag from the previous step should be attached to the relevant projects (the SA needs to access). It is done in the "IAM Manage Resources": https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing#attaching
3. When creating the SA in the organization level and choosing its permissions - a condition with the created tag should be attach to the permissions for that SA. See the screenshot below:

[image: Creating condition based on resource tags]

Finally, the SA created in organization level with permissions that have a condition based on the tag - would be able to access only the projects that have the same tag.

Comment: Please add details such as an example.